# Spinning cube when triggered - C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm completely new to coding so any help would be of great value.

I am trying to get a cube (which is an imported FBX with materials) to spin when the collider enters the box collider of the cube. I have been following 2 tutorials to get me going. The first is a spinning cube, which I completed successfully and the second is adding sound/music to the game when a 'Trigger Zone' is entered, again, this was no problem.

I would now like the cube to spin when the trigger zone is entered, so I thought I would be able to combine the 2 and make it work, but after a good while I've come to a dead end. Due to my lack of understanding I have no idea why what I have written isn't working when the script is added to the cube.

The cube tutorial I followed - https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/spinning-cube

The music tutorial I followed - https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/audio/adding-music-your-game

And my unsuccessful attempt at a spinning cube based on combining the above -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TriggerSpinControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed1 = 25f;
    public float speed2 = 100f;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.CompareTag("TriggerZone"))

            {

             transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, speed1 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }

        void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.CompareTag("TriggerZone"))
            {

            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, speed2 * Time.deltaTime);
            }

        }


}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

---

Following on from Rutter's answer below I have tried creating a script (based on vaious bits and pieces of of information from other questions and answers) that calls for 2 Spin scripts to be run on the TriggerEnter and TriggerExit, but since I'm still trying figure out and understand what I'm doing, it doesn't seem to be working.

The spin scrips are not attached to a game object but are just in the Assets folder.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TriggerSpinControl : MonoBehaviour

{ 
    private SpinFast spinfast;
    private SpinSlow spinslow;


        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
        if (other.CompareTag("TriggerZone"))

            {           

               spinfast = GetComponent<SpinFast>();   
            }

        }

        void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.CompareTag("TriggerZone"))
            {

              spinslow = GetComponent<SpinSlow>();

            }

        }


}
```

It could just be a load of nonsense, but I'm hoping I'm on the right track.

Thanks

Comment: Use OnTriggerStay() :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnTriggerEnter` will be called once when an object enters the trigger.

`OnTriggerExit` will be called once when an object exits the trigger.

If you want the object to *keep spinning*, you may want to try a different strategy.

`OnTriggerStay` is another event that will be called roughly once per frame for each object that is currently within the trigger. This would allow you to call `transform.Rotate` once per frame to keep spinning a little bit on each frame. This is a simple but brittle solution.

Unity is a "component-based" architecture -- each of your scripts is a component, and it's often advantageous to combine multiple components that work together. You could create one script that manages the spinning behavior in an `Update` event that gets called once per frame, then create another component that enables and disables the spinning script based on trigger entry/exit.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

Code (C#):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TriggerSpinControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed1 = 25f;
    public float speed2 = 100f;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, speed2 * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "MainCamera")
        {
            enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "MainCamera")

        {

            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, speed1 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "MainCamera")
        {

            enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```